# Lower bound generic in java does not compile even when passing super class

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard

`List<? super IOException>` means the list can contain `IOException` objects or any object that is `super` class of `IOException`. Then why the below Line 2 does not compile?

Also in Line 3 `FileNotFoundException` is not a `super` class of `IOException`. Then why it compiles?

```
List<? super IOException> myList =  new ArrayList<Exception>();
myList.add(new Exception());     //Line 2 This line do not compile
myList.add(new FileNotFoundException());  //Line 3 This compiles
```

Answer (score 7):

The wildcard lower bound specifies a lower bound for the type argument, not for the acceptable types of the `List`.  The type argument could be something as specific as `IOException`, but it could be as general as we can get: `Object`.

When adding an `Exception`, the type of the item is too general as an item, because the type parameter may be too specific for it -- it could be `IOException`.  The compiler won't allow you to add an `Exception` to something that may take only `IOException`s, so it generates the error.

This doesn't occur with `FileNotFoundException`, because no matter how specific the type parameter is, it won't be any more specific than `IOException` (the lower bound), so a [`FileNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), which is a subclass of `IOException`, is legal in all cases, so the compiler allows it.

Comment: Sorry I have a confusion. Here by writing `? super IOException` I am specifying an Lower bound that the List can contain only the super classes of `IOException` and it cannot contain any sub class of it. So the compiler should allow to add `Exception` object and give error while adding `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: As I've explained, you have a misunderstanding of what a lower bound is.  It's a lower bound of the type parameter, not of the items the list may contain.  You may assign a `List<IOException>` or a `List<Object>` to `myList`.  But either way, you can add a `FileNotFoundException` to `myList`, because a `FileNotFoundException` is a subtype of any possible type parameter.  But you may not add an `Exception` to `myList`, because the type parameter may be `IOException`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
myList.add(new FileNotFoundException());
```

compiles because `FileNotFoundException` *is* an `IOException`, just as it *is* an `Exception`, so it satisfies the bound of `myList`.

This:

```
myList.add(new Exception());
```

does *not* compile because the compiler does not know what *exact* type the list is (it doesn't check what was assigned to the varaible, it only looks at its declared type), so it doesn't know if the list assigned to it has a type that matches a super type of `IOException`, but not `Exception`.

This would happen is there was an intermediate class in the hierarchy between `Exception` and `IOException`. If the list actually had that type, `Exception` may not match the bound of the actual list assigned to `myList`.

The compiler doesn't check the complete class hierarchy nor what was assigned. It only does a basic check that always avoids runtime errors.

This is also true more generally where "logically" there is no code path that will cause an error, but the compile still fails.

Answer (score 0):

myList references a List that could be `List<IOException>` or `List<Exception>` or
`List<Object>`. Line 2 does not compile because we could have a `List<IOException>` and
an Exception object wouldn’t fit in there

`File-NotFoundException` can also be added to any of those three types. This is tricky because
`FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException` and the keyword says `super`.

The compiler looks at the reference type: `List<? super IOException>` all the possible types so:

```
List<Object>
List<Exception>
List<IOException>
```

then it goes across the line `myList.add(new Exception());` and sees that it cant compile because it couldnt fit in the `List<IOException>`